# Display clicked array item

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a php multidimesional array:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<?php
$brand = array (
"nike" => array (
                array( all deal 1 info in here),
                array( all deal 2 info in here),
                array( all deal 3 info in here)),
"puma" = array(
                array( all deal 1 info in here),
                array( all deal 2 info in here),
                array( all deal 3 info in here)),
"addidas" = array(
                array( 'logo'=>'images/addidas.png', 'description'=>'some addidas text'),
                array( all deal 2 info in here),
                array( all deal 3 info in here)),
);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var brand = <?php echo json_encode($brand) ?>;
for (var n in brand){
for (var i in brand[n]){
    // for jQuery("body").append jQuery is necessary, but of course you can work otherwise with this   data, too
    jQuery("body").append('<a href="' + brand[n][i].logo + '">' + brand[n][i].description + '</a>');
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is convert this into a javascript array, loop through and print out each brand as a hyperlink.  So if someone clicks addidas for example, this would display the content in a container div.  I have tried the suggestions so far but its not behaving the way I would like.

I would like to display the brand names as hyperlinks in a div and if you click say the Addidas link, it will pull just the Addidas content in to a content div:

```
<div id="brand-nav">
<a links here>
</div>

<div id="deals-content">
on click of a link, brand specific content here

</div>
```

Thanks everyone for you kind contributions, so any additional help much appreciated.

Volterony

Answer (score 0):

you can transform it into a JSON Array

```
var brand= "<?php echo json_encode($brand) ?>"
```

Comment: you mean to say multidimentional array does not exist in javascript? if so its wrong.

Comment: You should really do `var brand = <?php echo json_encode($brand) ?>;`.  That way it's already an object, and doesn't need to be parsed.

Comment: multidimensionnal array in javascript are indeed embeded array and are different from PHP multidimensionnal array

Answer (score 0):

Convert your PHP array into a javascript array via json_encode and after that iterate over it and e.g. append it to the body:

```
var brand = <?php echo json_encode($brand) ?>;
for (var n in brand){
    for (var i in brand[n]){
        // for jQuery("body").append jQuery is necessary, but of course you can work otherwise with this data, too
        jQuery("body").append('<a href="' + brand[n][i].logo + '">' + brand[n][i].description + '</a>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me.  I have updated the question but still no further forward.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the structure of your array before I convert it to javascript with one of the methods described above:

```
$brands = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'nike',
        'deals' => array(
            array('all deal 1 info in here'),
            array('all deal 2 info in here'),
            array('all deal 3 info in here'),
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'puma',
        'deals' => array(
            array('all deal 1 info in here'),
            array('all deal 2 info in here'),
            array('all deal 3 info in here'),
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'adidas',
        'deals' => array(
            array('logo' => 'images/addidas.png', 'description' => 'some addidas text'),
            array('all deal 2 info in here'),
            array('all deal 3 info in here'),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Reason being that associative arrays are maps, but it looks like you're storing a list of brands instead of hardcoding the number of brands that you have.

I know PHP lets you easily iterate over associative arrays (in fact so does javascript with objects) but I believe it's bad practice...

**EDIT: Added PHP solution (Display only)**

```
<?php foreach ($brands as $brand): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $brand['url'] ?>" title="<?php echo $brand['description'] ?>"><img src="<?php echo $brand['logo'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $brand['description'] ?>" /></a>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

**EDIT: I read all this javascript stuff and thought you needed it... ignore below if you don't need to convert to javascript**

then with the above array you can put it into your javascript as mentioned in other answers:

```
var brands = <?php json_encode($brands) ?>;
```

Where brands will be:

```
[
    {
        "name": "nike",
        "deals": [
            {
                // All deal 1 info here
            },
            {
                // All deal 2 info here
            },
            {
                // All deal 3 info here
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "puma",
        "deals": [
            {
                // All deal 1 info here
            },
            {
                // All deal 2 info here
            },
            {
                // All deal 3 info here
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "adidas",
        "deals": [
            {
                "logo": "images/adidas.png",
                "description": "some adidas text"
            },
            {
                // All deal 2 info here
            },
            {
                // All deal 3 info here
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

Comment: Very kind of you to have taken the time to review my issue.